# What is difference between Prime Path Testing and Path Testing?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, white-box-testing

I got following types of white box testing list:

```
Control flow testing 
Data flow testing 
Branch testing 
Statement coverage 
Decision coverage 
Modified condition/decision coverage
Prime path testing 
Path testing
```

Could anyone give me example through code that what is difference between Prime Path Testing and Path Testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prime Path Testing is a special case of Path testing where: "A path (p) is prime if (p) is a maximal simple path i.e. (p) cannot be extended without losing simplicity."

This is a nice explanation:
http://studylib.net/doc/5705864/prime-path-coverage

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, to find a prime path, make the largest simple path you can make from your nodes, that is your prime path.
When you are making this largest possible simple path, make sure that no nodes appear twice ( except the entry and exit nodes )